# How do I update a variable (which is a list) with an updated list after using a function to alter it?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I need some help please, I have some code I've written which should manipulate a list using a function. The problem I'm having is keeping hold of this manipulated list to use in the main coding. For example, I created a list which contains names for 4 people queuing in line for tickets, I then input this list in a function to remove the 3rd in line. This will create a new list which I want to be able to manipulate outside of the function. Here is my code so far

```
def aLeave(aList,usrstr):

    tempq = []
    idx = 0
    found = False
    while idx < len(aList) and not found: #This section works out the index
        if aList[idx] == usrstr:          # of the user string that needs removed
            found = True                  # from the queue list.
        else:
            idx = idx + 1

    if found:        
        for i in range(len(aList)):           #This sections takes the index previously 
            if i == idx:                      #found and uses it to create a new list
                continue                      #without the element the user has requested to be removed
            tempq.append(aList[i])

    aList = tempq
    print(aList)
    return aList

aList = ["john","mark","pete","dave"]

aLeave(aList,input("what do you want to remove"))

print (aList)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks (The function is called 'aLeave')

Comment: `aList` is a *local variable* inside your function. Assigning to it won't modify the global `aList`. You could use `global aList` at the top of your function, but that is bad design. Rather, you should just `return` the list, as you have. But then, you have to do something like `aList = aLeave(aList, input('...'))` or else the return value isn't assigned to anything, is no longere referenced, and gets garbage collected. You also could just `return tempq` and leave out `aList = tempq` in your function.

Comment: Also, you really don't need to use two loops to accomplish what you are doing. Just `for x in aList: if x != usrstr: tempq.append(x)`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga I realised it could be done simpler after I wrote the code. I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to assign the return value of the function to a variable, and since you want to update the same list, you can do something like this while calling the function.

```
aList = aLeave(aList, input("Stuff"))
```

Also, inside the function, `aList = tempq` is not necessary, since all it is doing is updating the local variable, aList. To update the aList in the global scope, you can write `global aList` at the top of the function, however, this is not considered good design practice, and should be avoided as far as possible.

Comment: Thanks @Shubham Jindal. I had extra lines of code in to try and make it work. Have slimmed it down and managed to return the new list also. :)